# Dynamic Disk Start on Boot

Tags: hard-drive, dynamic

Is there a way to make a Dynamic Disc Automatically Come on line after a reboot.  at the moment i must manually Bring the disk "online".

I was thinking a Startup Script would do the trick.  does anyone know of a URL HOWTO or a Premade script to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
echo  > c:\script.scr select disk X
echo >> c:\script.scr online
echo  > c:\script.scr select disk Y
echo >> c:\script.scr online
diskpart < c:\script.scr
```

Where X & Y are the Number of the Disk

Answer (score 0):

If you are refering to a windows server with dynamic discs for RAID for example it should come online on its own. If it is not online then there must have been a problem with the RAID or the controller. In that case it goes offline and you have solve the problem and then rightclick and reactivate it.

Comment: These disc's are iSCSI disks mounted with the iscsi.clp in windows. 

When they are BASIC discs they mount after reboot.  but when they are DYNAMIC disc they must be brought to an ONLINE state by script or hand.